# Eclipse reporting an array's clone() method is from it's corresponding type (including primitives)?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, clone

[image]

I was under the assumption that when eclipse suggests methods, it's in the form

```
 <methodName>(<any parameters>) : <retunType> - <actual class the method will be invoked from>
```

And it seems to be true for all the methods (but clone()) in the posted picture also.

But for `clone()`, eclipse says the method comes from the type of the array (`byte` in this case).

It's the same for all **arrays of primitive types** and **arrays of reference types** as well.

Eg: For `String[]` it gives `clone() : String[] - String`

What does that mean? Is my understanding wrong? Or is there something else in the `clone()` method?

Just to make things clear, my question is **Why does eclipse say "clone()" is from byte when it should be from byte[] just like "length"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be answered by looking at the eclipse source code.

The answer for your question is simple and disappointing: The Eclipse UI code which produces the complete proposals builds a faulty display. Note that the complete proposal for the length property of an array shows the correct type (byte[] in your example).

The details:

When you trigger the completion assistant the possible completions are calculated as [CompletionProposals](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/core/CompletionProposal.java).

The property of the CompletionProposals which is used to display the type of a proposed method or field completion is the declaringTypeSignature (see below).

[CompletionTests](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.model/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests/model/CompletionTests.java) shows that proposal objects for the clone-method and the length-field of a byte array would have a declaringTypeSignature "[B".

Now [CompletionProposalLabelProvider](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/text/java/CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java) takes these proposal objects and builds the view, in the form of a `StyledString`. Method `#createLabelWithTypeAndDeclaration` does it for field proposals, method `#createMethodProposalLabel` for method proposals. They have different implementations for the display of the declaring type.

The method display calls [SignatureUtil.stripSignatureToFQN](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20extension/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/template/java/SignatureUtil.java), passing "[B" as signature. The returned result has stripped of all array information and is simply "byte".

The field display calls [Signature.getSignatureSimpleName](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/core/Signature.java) passing "[B". This method does not ignore the array information and returns "byte[]".

Comment: Based on the above analysis (many thanks!) this bug has been fixed, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/473101

Answer (score -1):

This is because cloning depends on the type of the object. It depends on the memory size of the objects or primitive data types.

clone() method is actually the method of the 'Object' superclass. Other classes are supposed to override this and implement their own implementation for safe cloning. If nothing is provided, the normal cloning of Object class is called and implemented.

That is why, cloning an array depends on the type of data that array holds and the clone method of that data type will be called. If you have an int[], clone for int will be called. if you have Class A, and 'a' is the object of class A, and you have array of 'a' objects (a[]), clone from class A will be called.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Because, and array can be seen as a collection of any kind of object/data type. If you choose int array, an array class has no way of knowing how much space an int takes. If you choose Object array, array class has no way of knowing how much space an object takes. So it deffers that responsibility to the class of which the array is of. That is why clone() arrives from data type and not from array class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cloning an array does not clone its contained elements, clone from class A won't be called for `A[]`.